# How to call MessageBox within photochooser task

Tags: windows-phone-7, messagebox, dispatcher

I have a code where I am calling photochooser in WP7 and I want to show a messagebox to user when the pic is more than 2Mb. When I try to do this, since the photochooser task is running in background, we start getting unhandled exceptions.

```
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
       if (e.ChosenPhoto != null)
       {
           ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

           image = _UploadImgeViewModel.ReadToEnd(e.ChosenPhoto);
           if (image.Length < 16384)
           {
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
                UserSession.ProfileImage = bi;
                Session.PreviousImage = bi;
                UserSession.isImageChanged = true;
                UserSession.image = image;
                UserSession.Uploadimage = image;
                NavigationService.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler(navigateCompleted);
            }
            else
            {
                ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                UserSession.isImageChanged = false;
                UserSession.ProfileImage = null;


                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("The message")); 
            }
        }
}       

#endregion
```

This only shows the background job as resuming... and the msg box in foreground. and after a few seconds, the app crashes.
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Why are you running the `PhotochooserTask` in the background? And what errors do you get?

Comment: You have 10 seconds to return to the foreground completely or your app will be killed. If you have a messagebox that can display here, you will fail certification (because user could not click anything for 10 seconds) -- you need to wait for the page to load.

Comment: I am simply using the photochooser task to upload profile img for a user in my app. While doing that, I want to show a msg to the user is the image is more than 2Mb while the photochooser is still running in background. Actually, MessageBox stops photochooser and I just see resuming... and progress bar at the back and the app crashes. When I remove this MessageBox, there is no crash seen

Comment: Wellmel -  I think thats what is happening. Can you tell me what can be a workaround for this?

Comment: The PhotoChooserTask is no longer running after it comes back to your app. Where in your code are you uploading anything? In your code, there's no reason to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` for the MessageBox.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem. Can you show more code? How/Where are you calling the PhotoChooserTask? When is called the code you provided? In the PhotoChooserTask's Completed event?

Comment: I added more code here.keyboardP- If I give a simple  Messagebox call here, the Messagebox is shown and the app crashes after a few seconds if I don't click ok.

Comment: I still don't see why you have the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. Remove that and just keep the MessageBox and see if that helps. If you want to do the upload on a background thread, you don't have to put the entire completed event on it, just the upload section.

Answer (score 1):

Cool. I got some idea to resolve this. Might not be a fix, but this way we can avoid this issue. Just add a button and do the validating process in the button click event. Since we can't display the message box when the navigation is in progress.

Below is the code:

```
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.ChosenPhoto != null)
        {
            ProcessSelectedImage(e.ChosenPhoto);
        }
    }       
    private void ProcessSelectedImage(Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            bi.SetSource(stream);
            UserSession.ProfileImage = bi;
            UserSession.PreviousImage = bi;
            image = ConvertToImage.ReadToEnd(stream);
            UserSession.image = image;
            UserSession.Uploadimage = image;

        }
    }



    private void UploadImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (image.Length < 16384)
        {
            UserSession.isImageChanged = true;
            UserSession.image = image;
            UserSession.Uploadimage = image;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/EditMyProfile.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }
        else
        {

            UserSession.isImageChanged = false;
            UserSession.ProfileImage = null;
            UserSession.IsChangingProfilePicture = true;
            MessageBox.Show(MessageContent.ImageUploadLengh);

        }
    }
```

Thanks
Kamal

Answer (score 0):

You have 10 seconds to return to the foreground completely or your app will be killed. If you have a messagebox that can display here, you will fail certification (because user could not click anything for 10 seconds) -- you need to wait for the page to load.

A workaround for this if you need to show a MessageBox is to set a bool, and check it in the Page's Loaded event.

```
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e) { if (e.ChosenPhoto != null) { ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            image = _UploadImgeViewModel.ReadToEnd(e.ChosenPhoto);
            if (image.Length < 16384)
            {
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
                UserSession.ProfileImage = bi;
                Session.PreviousImage = bi;
                UserSession.isImageChanged = true;
                UserSession.image = image;
                UserSession.Uploadimage = image;
                NavigationService.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler(navigateCompleted);
            }
            else
            {
                ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                UserSession.isImageChanged = false;
                UserSession.ProfileImage = null;

//set flag
                UserSession.ImageTooBig = true;
            }
        }
    }       

    #endregion


MyPage()
{
//make sure you attach Loaded Event if not already
Loaded += (s,e) => 
{
    if (UserSession.ImageTooBig)
     {
       UserSession.ImageTooBig = false;
       MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the image exceeds 2 MB");
      }
};
}
```

Comment: Page loaded event does not get trigerred once we come back from photo chooser task or camera task...Let me check invoking this in Focus event.